# How do I fix "Cannot find module" when importing files from custom absolute path?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I tried to create a NodeJS from scratch with TypeScript and had a file structures below:

```
my-project
|
|--node_modules
|--src
|   |--index.ts
|   |--test.ts
|
|--package.json
|--tsconfig.json
|--...
```

Then in `tsconfig.json`, I added `baseUrl` and `paths` to allow absolute import

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",                                 
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "ESNext"],                                       
    "experimentalDecorators": true,                   
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    
    "module": "CommonJS",                                
    "moduleResolution": "Node",                      
    "baseUrl": ".",                                 
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@root/*": ["*"]
    },                                                 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,  
    "sourceMap": true,                                
    "outDir": "./build",                                   
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
    "strict": true,                                     
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

I created simple codes like this, VSCode still detects `test.ts` and passes linter check with strict mode.

```
// src/test.ts
export const a = 1;
```

```
// src/index.ts
import { a } from '@src/test'
console.log(a);
```

After that, I ran `npx nodemon src/index.ts` the terminal shows me an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@src/test'
Require stack:
- D:\self-project\typeorm-test\src\index.ts
```

Am I configuring path wrong? Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only work around I could find to this was to install [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) as a dev dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths
```

I also have [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) installed as a dev dependency. Then in your scripts in package.json add this:

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec npx ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register
```